# Team Explorer Everywhere - Remove Ignored files from Pending Changes

Tags: eclipse, tfs, tfvc, team-explorer-everywhere

Is there any way to remove pending changes from the Pending Changes list in Team Explorer Everywhere for TFS?

I've added a .tpignore file to my project, and I'm excluding certain things that I don't want in source control (build, WEB-INF, etc). However, it looks like team explorer everywhere picked up on these files before the ignore file was added, since they remain in the pending changes list.

I can see that eclipse is at least picking up that they should be ignored, because they all have the [Ignored] label in the project tree. I would have thought that adding files to the ignore file would automatically remove any pending changes that existed for the files....

Any idea how I can remove these items from the pending changes? I can't checkin until this is resolved because I don't want to mess up my source history with all of these extraneous files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct - Team Explorer Everywhere applies the .tpignore filter when it detects that the files were added to your Eclipse workspace.  If you edited the .tpignore file after they were detected then they will remain pended - ignoring resources is not done retroactively.

You'll have to undo these pending changes manually, by right clicking on the resource in an editor or a view and selecting Undo Pending Changes.  If you have whole folders full of files to undo, you can select a folder in the Package Explorer and undo pending changes for that folder recursively.

Comment: Doh - I guess that should have been more obvious to me - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Pending Changes window lets you select multiple files and undo them all at once.  This seems to be the easiest way to undo the damage.

Answer (score 0):

Or, simply within your Team Explorer Window...

1. Choose 'Home'.
2. Re-choose Pending Changes

To recalc what should be considered 'Pending changes'

Comment: It's important to note that this is only for *local workspaces*, whereas `.tpignore` applies to resources in Eclipse that are automatically changed when using *server workspaces*.  (The local workspace equivalent is `.tfignore`.)